# How prevent a user log in twice with the same username - using Rails Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

How prevent a user log in twice with the same username - using Rails Authlogic?

Answer (score 0):

You mean [Avoid multiple sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279248/authlogic-and-multiple-sessions-for-the-same-user) ?

Comment: That looks like it, but what is "record"? When I implement that piece of code I get: "The error occurred while evaluating nil.reset_persistence_token"

Thank, Michal.

Comment: This code needs to be added to the UserSession model. Not the User one.
The "record" represents the user that's trying to log himself in.

Comment: It is in UserSession, exactly how instructed, and it is nil.

Comment: Do you have the last version of authlogic ?

Comment: I do have the latest version indeed, I don't understand why it doesn't work :(

Comment: OK, so it seems that record is only nil, when an automatic logout happens (a user session timeout).