# Rails Authlogic prevent multiple login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am using Rails Authlogic and i want to prevent same user to log in twice at the same time ,I found a way to invalidate all user session and allow only the new one (sign out the user from any other device and only allow the new one) but that not what i want ,i want to prevent the new log in and keep the already logged in

Comment: Related question has been asked on following post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279248/authlogic-and-multiple-sessions-for-the-same-user

Comment: this link doesn't do what i want,he logout all other users and let the new one sign in ,but what i want to do is to prevent the new one from logging in

Answer (score -1):

You may refer this site. I think this site is suitable for your question [click here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: isn't there a way to do it without using device ?

Comment: many gem files are there but device is the best of them, in my point of view

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279248/authlogic-and-multiple-sessions-for-the-same-user